# Dataframes the most efficient way to fill the column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, list-comprehension

I'm trying to fill the dataframe column. I want to do it with ".iat" using loop. But traditional for loop is really slow and filling the column with 100 000 values using for loop is not efficient. List comprehension do it faster but create useless list which I wouldn't use. I also thought map method but it also creates useless map object. So I want to it similar to map but without creating any array,mapobject,etc. What is the fastest method for doing such a thing?

Comment: It depends what you're filling it with. Can you [edit] to provide a [mcve] with sample input, expected output, and code for what you're tried so far based on your own research?

Comment: Also, what/why are your constraints on creating "additional objects"? Is your concern processing power, limited memory, time efficiency?

Comment: I will edit it tomorrow because I left my code on the other computer. I was concerned about only time efficiency.

Comment: There's generally no penalty to time for generating a list via list comprehension, unless the same operation could be vectorized. You also wouldn't "create a useless list" unless you explicitly declare a list object and then add it to the df. If you do `df['col']=[i**2 for i in some_list]` then the column _is_ the list.

Comment: "*Most efficient way*" is most often not compatible with "*I want to do it with ".iat" using loop*"

Answer (score 0):

In terms of time efficiency, using numpy arrays seem to win when measured with %timeit (using vscode + ipython interactive terminal).

```
#%%
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np 

size = 1000000

def makelarge_random():
    return pd.DataFrame(pd.Series((random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(size))))

def makelarge_constant():
    return pd.DataFrame(pd.Series((55 for i in range(size))))

def makelarge_empty_numpy():
    return pd.DataFrame(np.empty(size, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype))

def makeints_numpy():
    return pd.DataFrame(np.arange(stop = size))

print(f"Time to instantiate dataframe with length {size} from various methods")
print(" --- ")
print(makelarge_random.__name__)
%timeit makelarge_random()
print(" --- ")
print(makelarge_constant.__name__)
%timeit makelarge_constant()
print(" --- ")
print(makelarge_empty_numpy.__name__)
%timeit makelarge_empty()
print(" --- ")
print(makeints_numpy.__name__)
%timeit makeints_numpy()
#%%
```

> Output:

```
Time to instantiate dataframe with length 1000000 from various inputs
 --- 
makelarge_random
550 ms ± 2.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
 --- 
makelarge_constant
139 ms ± 2.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
 --- 
makelarge_empty_numpy
10 ms ± 94.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
 --- 
makeints_numpy
641 µs ± 31.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I meant different thing. I know to efficiently init the df, but I want to do sth like that : I have list of full dates and another dataframe which consist of another dataframes. I want to put into new_df dates from the shorter df in the same row as these from bigger df. On the positions which are in the longer df and not in shorter I want to put empty string. So the best option for me as I think is with using numpy where and df.iat with looping over shorter df. But the fastest option is with map or list comprehension so I will create useless object.